# How to set variable as database password into pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, environment-variables, pom.xml

I need to configure a Jenkins variable as my password database into my pom's profile, but if I set `${env.passwordb}` (as shown below) the project does not compile and get some errors, but if I push the code to Jenkins, it takes the variable and runs the project perfectly. What I need to change ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.vrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-vrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${env.urlTomcat}</url>
                    <path>${env.appPath}</path>
                    <username>${env.username}</username>
                    <password>${env.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>company-vrs</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>visitors</finalName>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.jks</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.company.vrs.config.AppConfig</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>9.2.0.RC0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>asta que
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <port>9090</port>
                            <path>/</path>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <db.url>jdbc:postgresql://hsvvrsdev.company.com:5432/vrs_dev</db.url>
                <db.username>vrsuser</db.username>
                <db.password>${env.passworddb}</db.password>
                <isdev>true</isdev>
                <realm.metadata.file>/metadata/secureAuth_dev.xml</realm.metadata.file>
                <realm.metadata.url>https://ssodev.company.com/SecureAuth68/metadata.xml</realm.metadata.url>
                <realm.url.restart>https://ssodev.company.com/SecureAuth68/restart.aspx</realm.url.restart>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>sqa</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>visitors_sqa</finalName>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.jks</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.company.vrs.config.AppConfig</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>9.2.0.v20140526</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <port>9090</port>
                            <path>/</path>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <db.url>jdbc:postgresql://hsvvrsdev.company.com:5432/vrs_sqa</db.url>
                <db.username>vrsuser</db.username>
                <db.password>vrs#2015!</db.password>
                <istest>true</istest>
                <realm.metadata.file>/metadata/secureAuth_dev.xml</realm.metadata.file>
                <realm.metadata.url>https://ssodev.company.com/SecureAuth68/metadata.xml</realm.metadata.url>
                <realm.url.restart>https://ssodev.company.com/SecureAuth68/restart.aspx</realm.url.restart>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>pro</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>visitors</finalName>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.jks</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.company.vrs.config.AppConfig</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>9.2.0.v20140526</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <port>9090</port>
                            <path>/</path>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <db.url>jdbc:postgresql://hsvvrsdb.company.com:5432/vrs</db.url>
                <db.username>vrsuser</db.username>
                <db.password>v14r3s20150302</db.password>
                <ispro>true</ispro>
                <realm.metadata.file>/metadata/secureAuth_prod.xml</realm.metadata.file>
                <realm.metadata.url>https://sso.company.com/visitors/metadata.xml</realm.metadata.url>
                <realm.url.restart>https://sso.company.com/visitors/restart.aspx</realm.url.restart>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <spring-data-jpa-version>1.6.1.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa-version>
        <spring-data-commons-version>1.8.1.RELEASE</spring-data-commons-version>
        <hibernate-version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate-version>
        <org-slf4j-version>1.7.7</org-slf4j-version>
        <spring-ldap-version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-ldap-version>
        <spring-security-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
        <bonecp-version>0.8.0.RELEASE</bonecp-version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
           ..... many dependencies ....        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'env.passworddb' in string value "${env.passworddb}"

Comment: I dont see env.passwordb variable in that pom.. am i missing smoething?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski sorry, I had another name. I change by <db.password>${env.passworddb}</db.password> now.

Comment: how do you run the build locally?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I'm using IntelliJ but it detects an error in the pom as if the syntax was wrong and also this project runs with maven with the command line: clean install jetty:run. I hope I have answered your question.

Comment: ok how do you configure your PropertyPlaceholder bean in spring?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski this project uses annotation configuration to resolve the beans instead of web.xml, also uses hibernate to execute the database transactions.

Comment: Just so that i understand this correctly.. where in the application is this property replaced.. in some properties file? I dont think i get the picture .. can you post the entire process of the usage of this property with details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134392/discussion-between-angel-cuenca-and-maciej-kowalski).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of investigation it turned out that the ${env.passwddb} existed only on the remote jenkins environment. To overcome that and still use the same profile connfiguration, the possible solutions would be:

**1)** Hardcode

On local environment the password ought to be hardcoded inside the properties file. One the remote, the placeholder would still be present.

**2)** Password passed through maven command line:

```
mvn clean package resources:testResources -Denv.passwddb=realpass
```

Comment: 1) sounds like a dangerous solution, especially if the hardcoded value might end up inside your repository. You could also try to set the variable using a Maven profile inside your `.m2/settings.xml` file.